# Ubuntu asks for wi-fi login before loggining into an account (i.e. on boot)

Tags: networking, login, 22.04

Before going on,this is NOT a duplicate of
[How to disable WiFi and Ethernet at login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1188697/how-to-disable-wifi-and-ethernet-at-login)

Ubuntu 22.04
kernel 5.15.0-60-generic

When I boot the system, on the login screen I always get asked the password to a Wi-Fi network. It seems that it is going over the connected networks in my login account before I enter the password, and asking me for the Wi-Fi password.

What is annoying is that if I don't enter the password or press "cancel", I cannot enter the login password and login to my account.

[image: This is what a dialogue looks like]

## Goal

I want to disable network before logging into the account on the login screen.

Comment: How did this happen? It is an unconventional behavior. To find a solution on how to disable it, you need to find out how you've enabled it ;-)

Comment: I have no idea. I left UK, and went to Japan, and I connected my parent's home network and this started happening... I thought this information won't help, so I left it out.

Comment: Maybe some screenshots can give a clue...

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for the help, I've added a screenshot.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I am sure someone will find a way. Probably NetworkManager is started two early for some reason. Most likely you ran some wrong command to connect.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you anyway, I'll try to look for solution in that angle too!

Comment: Are you connected hardwired then?  This looks like the password for that WiFi network is not stored or not storing properly.  You may need to check your visited WiFi connections Network -> Wireless settings.  If you are connecting hardwired and want the WiFi to not attempt the connection in the Wireless settings uncheck the Connect Automatically.  I am also thinking here that you found a bug as it should be asking for WiFi network login passwords after your login and not before.  That should be filed with Canonical so they can track and fix it.

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Try to fix the original problem - that login dialog doesn't belong there.

Comment: @kanehekili This is not X-Y problem. There is no attempt is made for solving the problem (wifi is asked before login). I think I need to modify the title.

Comment: @Terrance Looks like a serious security bleach if I let non-user to be able to login to a wifi-network of some user before they even login.

Comment: @Tom Each user should be allowed to choose their own WiFi networks.  This is why this should come up after the login and not before.

Comment: @Terrance Exactly. Therefore, the speculation "This looks like the password for that WiFi network is not stored or not storing properly. " I think is not the correct speculation. But otherwise I agree with you, and I will try to pass it on to Canonical.

Comment: @Tom If the password was stored properly it wouldn't be asking.  The issue though is when it is asking. That is where the bug comes in.  It should not be asking before you log in.  So it is like 2 bugs.